# cxf-xjc-plugin 4.0.0 + java17: javax.xml.bind.annotation and jakarta.xml.bind.annotation generated at random - why?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I have a project that generates code using cxf-xjc-plugin v4.0.0 as follows:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <extensions>
            <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-dv:4.0.0</extension>
          </extensions>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
              <xsdOptions>
                <xsdOption>
                  <xsd>src/main/resources/wadl/error.xsd</xsd>
                </xsdOption>
[snip 16 other xsds]
              </xsdOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

The code being generated fails to compile as follows:

```
[ERROR] /Users/minfrin/src/[snip]-trunk/target/generated/src/main/java/[snip].java:[8,33] package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
```

Digging deeper we find the code generator has generated classes for some of the XSDs like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
```

And for the rest of the XSDs like this:

```
//
// This file was generated by the Eclipse Implementation of JAXB, v3.0.2 
// See https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2023.07.09 at 12:09:03 PM BST 
//

[snip]

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
```

I am expecting one behaviour or the other, but both behaviours, at apparent random?

Anyone else seen this kind of behaviour before?

The comment at the top of the jakarta files says "This file was generated by the Eclipse Implementation of JAXB, v3.0.2", while no comment exists on top of the javax files.